# Getting error even after conforming to UIViewControllerRepresentable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

Whenever I try to use the below code snippet in our existing UIKit project, I get the following error. When I move the same code to another Xcode project, it works perfectly.
On clicking Xcode suggestion same function get added but with same error again.

> Type 'MyUIKitViewControllerWrapper' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MyUIKitViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyUIKitViewController {
        return MyUIKitViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyUIKitViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}


import Foundation
import UIKit
// Create your UIKit view controller
final class MyUIKitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set up your UIKit view controller
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello from UIKit!"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, clear cache, drrived data, etc. and build again. I see no issues in my Xcode.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini After removing the derived data and clear cache also showing the same error, Same code works in different project.